# Why did the girl try to seduce Amay at night, if she was the informer herself?

Tags: plot-explanation, raid

In *[Raid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raid_(2018_film))* (2018),  Amay (Ajay Devgan) knew from the beginning that the girl was the informer. And she also helped her lover to give the information. So why did she try to seduce him that night?